# create an account using web to case and link the registered case with that account

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, apex

I am new to the salesforce and referring to the URL: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=087300000006tuC.

- I would want to create the Contact automatically (using either phone or email). If phone or email matches create the web to case and link case to the account. Assume I have a HTML page for the Web to case.
- If phone or email does not present then create the account and then link the created case with the account.

What is the best approach to implement this? Could you please provide the steps to achieve this ?

I tried doing the Trigger from the link: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=087300000006tuC. This link looks something simillar to. 
**One thing I noticed that when web to case is created, Phone no is not registered in the case why ?**

```
trigger WebCaseAccountTrigger on Case (before insert) {

    Map<String, Case> phoneMap = new Map<String,Case>();

    for (Case caseObj : Trigger.new) {
        if(caseObj.Origin == 'web'){
            phoneMap.put(caseObj.ContactPhone, caseObj);
        }
    }

    List<Case> caseToBeUpdated = new List<Case>();

    List<Account> listAccounts = [SELECT Id, Name,AccountNumber, Phone FROM Account WHERE Phone IN :phoneMap.keySet()];

   // check if accounts has values 
    if(listAccounts != null && listAccounts.size() > 0){
        System.debug('List Account :'+listAccounts);
        for(Account acc : listAccounts){
            case updateCase = phoneMap.get(acc.Phone);
            updateCase.AccountId = acc.Id;
            caseToBeUpdated.add(updateCase);
        }
        System.debug('caseToBeUpdated : '+caseToBeUpdated);
    }else{
        // Need to implement yet.
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you done so far, this isn't code someone could write in 10 minutes, you will need to have a Trigger on Case `after insert` that would need to find any accounts that have an associated phone or email, then you will need to update it accordingly, if you didn't have anything associated you need to create the account and then update the Case..

Comment: `System.debug('List Account :'+listAccounts);` Showing correctly?

Comment: When I populate the Web to case HTML form no trigger is getting called. But I go to the Case -> Create new case then only Trigger is calling with the some exception. I only want trigger to be called using web to case HTML form. I am completely block on this issue. Also I updated my code above and some links

Comment: I don't think you understand how execution contexts work, the trigger is firing because you are inserting a Case.  Your trigger is firing.. https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/apex_basics_dotnet/units/execution_context

Comment: Can we not create it using Process Builder ?